# Cannot detect the headphone connected / disconnected

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, avfoundation

```
func areHeadphonesConnected() -> Bool {
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    
    do {
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
        
        let currentRoute = audioSession.currentRoute
        SDKLog(info: "currentRouteis\(currentRoute)")
        for output in currentRoute.outputs {
            SDKLog(info: "portType is\(output.portType)")
            SDKLog(info: "UID is\(output.uid)")
            if output.portType == AVAudioSession.Port.headphones  {
                try audioSession.setActive(false)
                return true
            }
        }
        
        try audioSession.setActive(false)
    } catch {
        print("Error checking headphone status: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    return false
}
```

i have the above code but the value it returns in port type is speaker even if the headset is connected.

the port type should return headphone if connected and speakers if headphone are not connected,

Comment: Just to verify: you're testing on an iPhone 6s or earlier device (~2015) running iOS 15, correct? That's the last generation that had a headphone port. Just wanted to verify before I break out my old devices to reproduce. Bluetooth connections are not "headphones" in this sense.

Comment: nope i have tested that using the wired headphones that has lightning cable so i was able to test it on the latest devices ie:iphone 14